# Encrypted Password Accessible via API Call, Is this Secure?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, encryption, password-encryption

I am working through some security concepts right now and I was curious if this method has been tried and/or if it is safe taking into consideration "Brute Forcing" is still possible.

Take for example a **Microsoft WebAPI Template** in **Visual Studio** where you access a endpoint using a "GET".

- The Endpoint would be accessible by any user/application
- The String value that a user/application would get from this endpoint would be the password they need, but encrypted using a "KeyValue"
- After a TLS Transmission of this Encrypted Value, the user/application would decrypt the String using their "KeyValue"

**Is this a secure practice?**

Thanks for indulging me and look forward to your responses.

**EDIT: Added Further Clarification with Image to Help Illustrate**

[image]

Comment: You need to pose the question against what you are trying to defend. If it is someone listening in on your communication thats what ssl/tls is for. 

If you want to hardcode a key at the application level to get some type of security on the users end: don't! you can not ensure that the user side has not been tampered with.

Which concludes all security verification should be done on the server side so you can ensure confidentiality and security.

Comment: Why would your application be retrieving a password?

Comment: @SeverinJaeschke, what danger would you propose from the User Side if all they are doing is consuming and decrypting the string? If we both share the same key at the time and my decryption fails, update the key on both sides.

Comment: @JamesKPolk, suppose I want to update a password that is stored in a database or configuration file that is shipped with an apps dependencies. Basically what I'm getting at.

Comment: How does your app get the "KeyValue" that it uses to decrypt the string?

Comment: @JamesKPolk, lets say that it is a hard-coded value that can be changed next deployment if need be so that the person/app can decrypt with the current KeyValue and it can be any length (techically it is be the Salt/Hash/etc that is used to decrypt and is kept private)

Comment: You see the problem. If the app is available to all then anyone can reverse engineer it and obtain the value, and do so without you ever knowing they have it.

Comment: @JamesKPolk in this situation, lets assume the app is NOT available to all and the app is something deployed on a Server that only administrators have access to. The user in this situation would literally only be a person doing a get request from their browser and manually decrypting by hand or with a tool using the KeyValue. Basically the only people who have the key value are the APP and lets say myself to just test to make sure the API does what it's supposed to via some manual methods.

Comment: @JamesKPolk, see my updated question at the top, I included an illustration to help better explain.

Comment: @SeverinJaeschke, updated the Initial Post at the top to help clarify.

Comment: Looks like server 1 is acting as a [KMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_management#Key_management_system) in this scenario, yes?

Comment: @Cody IMHO you are overcomplicating the things. As far I understood, the Web API would return an encrypted password for an authenticated user or application. Then - why even bother with encryption? Is TLS not enough? It is still not clear why are you doing that, what do you want to achieve.. If the service client are not authenticated, **assuming the password is properly encrypted** (salted, authenticated, etc..) the only issue stays the hardcoded decryption key. and `binaries are accessible only to admins` is a very strong assumption (usually wrong)

Comment: @gusto2, In my example consider the WebAPI is unauthenticated anyone can perform a "GET" and we are on an internal network inaccessible to the outside world with server security locked down. I consider TLS not enough purely because we are broadcasting a password so we need to encrypt the password. So you are saying that the only weak point in this scenario would be the "binaries" or is the whole solution flawed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the following 2 Scenarios:

> 1. Communication between Server and Client
>
>    **a.** Your Server serves the Client application with an encrypted password.
>
>    **b.** The Client can request any password.
>
>    **c.** The passwords are encrypted with a shared Key that is known by both server and client application

As James K Polk already pointed out:

A knowledgable Attacker can and will analyse your deployed application and at some point will find your hardcoded decryption key ("KeyValue"). What prevents him from requesting every password that is stored on the Server?

Rule of thumb here would be: "Do not trust the client side."

> 2. Communication between Server and Server
>
>    **a.** You have 2 server applications. **Application A** is acting as some kind of database server. **Application B** is your Back-End for a user application of some kind.
>
>    **b.** Application A serves paswords to any requester, not only Server B. With no type of authentication whatsoever.
>
>    **c.** Confidentiality is guaranteed through a shared and hard-coded Key.

I think you are trying to overcomplicate things hoping that no one is able to piece together the puzzle.

Someone with enough time and effort might be able to get information about your server compilation and/or be able to get the Code of Application B. Which again defaults in the scenario of 1. Another point is that there are enough bots out there randomly scanning ips to check responses. Application A might be found and even-though they do not have the shared key might be able to piece together the purpose of Application A and make this server a priority target.

**Is this a safe practice?**

No. It is never a good idea to give away possibly confidential information for free. Encrypted or not. You wouldn't let people freely download your database would you?

**What you should do**

All Authentication/Authorization (for example a user login, that's what I expect is your reason to exchange the passwords) should be done on the server side since you're in control of this environment.

Since you didn't tell us what you're actually trying to accomplish I'd recommend you read up on common attack vectors and find out about common ways to mitigate these.

A few suggestions from me:

1. Communication between 2 End-points -> SSL/TLS
2. Authorization / Authentication
3. [Open Web Application Security Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) and their [Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project) ([2017](https://www.owasp.org/images/7/72/OWASP_Top_10-2017_%28en%29.pdf.pdf))

Comment: make this server a priority target. -- This is a very good point, realistically I am just trying to find a way for any client application to be able to update it's password to a service, and I find it hard to come up with an easy way to update a deployments password if you don't have immediate access to update since most config files are embedded. This issue I have personally is we have apps deployed on Pivotal and once they go live in production it's hell to get the config changed since we would have no access to prod due to policy. AKA where my crappy dynamic idea came from.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean with it's password? What is the purpose of this password? 

Most web applications expect an authorization in the form of the users old password provided with the new password which is then exchanged in the server side database. 

But I get the feeling that is not the scenario we are talking about. 

Maybe an Authentication/Authorization Layer that uses your WebAPI?